# How to prevent pixelation on Safari browser when using filter?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, safari, svg-filters

In the below Demo I see in Safari that by applying

`svg {
   filter: blur(0); /* even with no-op filter */
}`

this happens only in Safari, but not in Chrome

```css
#scene {
   filter: blur(0); /* even with no-op filter */
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   transform: scale(6);
}
```

```html
<div id="scene">
  hello
</div>
```

How can I prevent pixelation while still keeping the drop-shadow on the SVG ?

Comment: [It's not limited to svg](https://jsfiddle.net/nrpgsvod/), it's simply they render css filters first and then transform the result, I doubt there is a workaround to this, but certainly is worth a bug report.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, that really narrow downs the problem,I raised a bug to Safari Team

Answer (score -1):

This happens because Safari is optimizing the scale and doing the transform on the GPU. You want to stop Safari doing this and force it to re-render on the CPU (this is less power efficient.)

The function you want to alter is most likely this one inside panzoom.js

```
  function applyTransform(transform) {
    svgElement.setAttribute('transform', 'matrix(' +
      transform.scale + ' 0 0 ' +
      transform.scale + ' ' +
      transform.x + ' ' + transform.y + ')')
  }
```

You want to add another attribute here in order to kick Safari to re-render. You might have to experiment with adding attributes like enable-background: new or shape-rendering: geometricPrecision to see what might work. Note - you might have to experiment a lot and there's no guarantee that whatever works will keep working.

Comment: I doubt a simple attribute will do anything here. Though my Safari just doesn't render anything at all when I force disable "*Accelerated Compositing*", disabling "*Full Page Accelerated Drawing¨" doesn't change anything. Note that it's not only limited to svg rendering, that's global to css filters. The thing is they first draw filters on bitmap canvas and then transform these canvas.

Comment: geometricPrecision  doesn't help , only way I found is that having rounded off values  for transform, but that kills the whole purpose of panning and zooming https://jsfiddle.net/dota2pro/q2syfLjv/